# When trying to use Kendo "flatten" function I am getting Error: Module not found:

Tags: angular, kendo-ui, node-modules, nodes, webstorm

I am getting error while I am trying to run/build Angular project.

I am trying to use flatten I my project. I have updated my kendo version to 13.5.0. Before it was imported from:

```js
import { flatten } from '@progress/kendo-angular-grid/dist/es2015/filtering/base-filter-cell.component';
```

Now it is imported from:

```js
import { flatten } from '@progress/kendo-angular-grid/filtering/base-filter-cell.component';
```

But I am getting the error:

> Error: Module not found: Error: Package path `./filtering/base-filter-cell.component` is not exported from package
> `C:\Users\X\WebstormProjects\X\node_modules\@progress\kendo-angular-grid` (see exports field in `C:\Users\X\WebstormProjects\X\node_modules\@progress\kendo-angular-grid\package.json`)

I have tried to import it with auto import. In the node modules `./filtering/base-filter-cell.component` the flatten function exists

- Angular: 16.2.5
- Node: 18.17.1
- Kendo: 13.5.0

Auto import and searching I could not find any info about this.